# Unity infinite loop of moving sprites (Slot Machine reel)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slot

I'm trying to make a slot machine prototype.
My goal is to simulate(programmatically) symbols movement. I want my symbols move down and when each symbol go out of game field, it should be moved to the frame's top again. Here is my code:

```
public class Reel : MonoBehaviour {

    public int reelHeight = 3;

    public int symbolWidth = 3;
    public int symbolHeight = 3;

    public float reelSpeed = 1000;

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject symbol;

    public List<GameObject> symbols = new List<GameObject>();

    private bool inSpin = false;

    void Start () {
        // reel predefined symbols
        int[] reelSymbols = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5}; //{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,5,5,5,5,2,2,6,6,6,6,3,7,7,7,7};

        // instantiating symbols on reel
        for (int i = 0; i < reelSymbols.Length; i++) {
            symbol = Instantiate (symbol, new Vector3 (0, i*symbolHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            symbol.GetComponent<Symbol>().symbolType = reelSymbols [i];
            symbols.Add (symbol);
        }
    }

    public void SpinReel () {
        inSpin = !inSpin;
    }

    void Update () {
        // infinite spin
        if (inSpin) {
            foreach (GameObject symbol in symbols) {
                // moving symbols down
                float currentReelSpeed = reelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                symbol.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * currentReelSpeed);

                // move symbol up to the top if it's go down and no longer vidible
                if (symbol.transform.position.y <= -3.0f) {
                    float newY = ((symbols.Count - 1) * symbolHeight) + transform.position.y;
                    symbol.transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, symbols.Count*symbolHeight, transform.position.z);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My symbol is a regular GameObject:

```
public class Symbol : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite [] sArray;

    public int symbolType;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sArray [symbolType];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

So, my symbols move but after the lowest symbol goes up again, gap between symbols is not the same.

[image: see image of bug]

If anyone have experience in making slot machines, please share it with me.
Thanks and have a nice day

Comment: At the first look your problem seems to be related to the `Translate` function since after a lot of iterations you are bound to lose some accuracy to floating point inaccuracy - on the other hand it looks a bit too extreme to be the only explanation so I'm not 100% sure yet, I'll try to reproduce that.

Comment: You calculate `newY` but you dont use it. You still set the y to  `symbols.Count*symbolHeight`. That might be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
if (symbol.transform.position.y <= -3.0f) 
{
    float newY = ((symbols.Count - 1) * symbolHeight) + transform.position.y;
    symbol.transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, symbols.Count*symbolHeight, transform.position.z);
}
```

You're checking if the symbol past the checking point so let's assume it's `transform.position.y` is equal to `-3.1f` and then you're trying to reset it on top by adding `3.0f` ( `symbolHeight` ) instead of the actual position change ( `3.1f` ). That's only an example and of course the values can vary.

---

To fix this I would suggest doing something like :

```
if (symbol.transform.position.y <= -3.0f) 
{
    Vector3 currentPosition = symbol.transform.position;
    currentPosition.y = (currentPosition.y + 3.0f) + (symbols.Count - 1) * symbolHeight;
    symbol.transform.position = currentPosition;
}
```

[Try this online](http://rextester.com/XGDAT20711)